# Preventing hover to behave like click on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

Project link:

```
http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/wp/usefulcase/
```

When you test the link in an iPhone and open the menu by click the button on top right, you will see that some menu items have submenu. When you click on the main menu item, the sub menu opens, but the page is redirected to the clicked item's link. I need to prevent that from happening.

Following is the js, that I have applied, but it is not working:

```
// see whether device supports touch events (a bit simplistic, but...)
var hasTouch = ("ontouchstart" in window);
var iOS5 = /iPad|iPod|iPhone/.test(navigator.platform) && "matchMedia" in window;

// hook touch events for drop-down menus
// NB: if has touch events, then has standards event handling too
// but we don't want to run this code on iOS5+
if (hasTouch && document.querySelectorAll && !iOS5) {
    var i, len, element,
        dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".menu li > a");

    function menuTouch(event) {
        // toggle flag for preventing click for this link
        var i, len, noclick = !(this.dataNoclick);

        // reset flag on all links
        for (i = 0, len = dropdowns.length; i < len; ++i) {
            dropdowns[i].dataNoclick = false;
        }

        // set new flag value and focus on dropdown menu
        this.dataNoclick = noclick;
        this.focus();
    }

    function menuClick(event) {
        // if click isn't wanted, prevent it
        if (this.dataNoclick) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    for (i = 0, len = dropdowns.length; i < len; ++i) {
        element = dropdowns[i];
        element.dataNoclick = false;
        element.addEventListener("touchstart", menuTouch, false);
        element.addEventListener("click", menuClick, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using google chrome on Android, when I click the menu button it does nothing.

Comment: I'm running an iPhone emulator. Also nothing.

Comment: Please reload, I am currently working on this. My apologies. The menu is working now.

Comment: Also, the menu is not working on the "Features" page due to a jQuery conflict, but it is working on every other page. But that is not the issue here.

Comment: In this scenario, how does the user access the actual menu button if he does not wat to go to any sub item? Double tap? Holding?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto, I am not sure what you are asking here. The menu slides in from left when a user clicks on the menu button on the top right. Then, when a menu item is clicked, it should show the menu/dropdown by a slide down effect and not redirect the page to the clicked item.

Comment: I'm asking: What if the user wants to redirect to the page he clicked? ...

Comment: Double click works, yes. Is there a better way to do this? Please let me know if there is.